# Approximating polygons from corrupted silhouette information

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Programming Language: C++, Python

I have some 2D silhouette information that is partially damaged and empty inside.  What I want is to approximate this silhouette with a polygon (maximum, octagon).  What approaches are possible for a solution?  Functions such as cv's findContours did not work well due to cut off.

[image]
Input silhouette

[image]
Output (I want)

Comment: welcome. please pick a programming language.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. My programming language is C++ and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two results in Python/OpenCV. The first gets the rotated rectangle about your figure. The second gets the convex hull about your figure and then reduces the number of vertices to 8.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the input as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('broken_polygon.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
hh, ww = img.shape

# threshold to binary
img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get non-zero points point
points = np.column_stack(np.where(img.transpose() > 0))

# compute rotated rectangle from thresholded non-zero coords
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(points)
print(rect)

# draw rotated rectangle on input
img_rect = img.copy()
img_rect = cv2.merge([img_rect,img_rect,img_rect])
box = np.intp(cv2.boxPoints(rect))
print('box:', box)
cv2.polylines(img_rect, [box], True, (0,0,255), 2)

# get convex hull
hull = cv2.convexHull(points)

# reduce vertices of convex hull
peri = len(hull)
poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(hull, 0.28 * peri, False)
print('num reduced vertices:', len(poly))

# draw polygon on copy of input
img_hbox = img.copy()
img_hbox = cv2.merge([img_hbox,img_hbox,img_hbox])
cv2.polylines(img_hbox, [poly], False, (0,0,255), 2)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('broken_polygon_rot_rect.jpg', img_rect)
cv2.imwrite('broken_polygon_hull_poly.jpg', img_hbox)

# show results
cv2.imshow('RotRect', img_rect)
cv2.imshow('HullPoly', img_hbox)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Rotated Rectangle:

[image]

Reduced Convex Hull Vertices:

[image]